# pandas en anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

Buenas amigos tengo un problema que no logro encontrar solucionarlo alguine me puede ayudar cuando ejecuto pandas desde un pequeño proyecto me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

resulta que esta instalado el paquete de pandas no logro resolverlo que pasa
gracias amigos por sus ayudas

despues de realizar el siguiente comando `where python` en la consola me resulto este mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero me puedan ayudar a solucionar este proble que me esta presentando que no se que pasa gracias amigos

Comment: No parece que estés usando la instalación de python que viene con anaconda. Seguramente has instalado pandas por tu cuenta fuera del _ecosistema_ anaconda. Abre una terminal y adjunta en tu pregunta el resultado de los comandos `where python` y `conda info --all`.

Comment: Reinstala pandas con conda... <conda install pandas>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigos por si les falla a ustedes encontr la forma de solucionarlo y de la siguiente manera teniendo en cuenta que anaconda no se actualiza constantemente es solo realizar los 3 siguientes pasos

```
pip uninstall pandas  
pip install pandas
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

de esta forma solucione este error gracias a los que me ayudaron

Comment: Procura mantener identificadas tus instalaciones de python y, si tienes más de una (como es tu caso), no des por sentado que estás ejecutando una en particular.

Comment: Si amigo lo he aprendido a tener en cuenta gracias